# Process 'command 'D:\Programms\jdk\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android

Пишу простое приложение под андроид (учусь). Почти само собой вылезла ошибка

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Programms\jdk\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

ps (изменил 2-3 строчки в коде и вылезла эта ошибка). Нажимал rebuild и все ок `Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL`, но при создании APK такая ошибка, что делать?

Comment: Ну... Попробуйте build.gradle выложить

Comment: Браузер мешал ему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается было мало ресурсов, закрыл браузер и все заработало